# Animating widget changes with Cubit: Animation not working despite widget rebuild

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I don't want to use setState to update the widget that should change, instead I want to use a cubit to just rebuild that specific widget, the problem is that the animation doesn't happen, the widget is changing, but it doesn't animate. Here's a screenshot of the code and the cubit I'm using.

```
final _animationCubit = AnimationCubit();

(...)
AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              child: BlocBuilder<AnimationCubit, bool>(
                key: ValueKey(
                  _animationCubit.state ? context.l10n.signIn : context.l10n.signOut,
                ),
                bloc: _animationCubit,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Text(
                    state ? context.l10n.signIn : context.l10n.signOut,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: context.textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                      color: context.colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
                    key: ValueKey(
                      _animationCubit.state ? 'add_${context.l10n.signIn}' : 'add_${context.l10n.signOut}',
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

cubit:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class AnimationCubit extends Cubit<bool> {
  AnimationCubit() : super(false);

  void isAnimationCompleted(bool isCompleted) => emit(isCompleted);
}
```

Emit a new value in this way:

```
 _animationCubit.isAnimationCompleted(!_animationCubit.state);
```

Comment: what happen if you use two separate Text widgets

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh same result

Comment: try to debug/print the state

Comment: I found a solution that said (and works) that i have to involve my AnimatedSwicher with the BlocBuilder